# NoMethodError undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass Pundit, Devise Rails

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, pundit

I'm trying to integrate pundit with my active admin and devise configuration. But the app works weirdly. It takes in model/record as current_user.

my policy file:

```
class AdminUserPolicy
  attr_reader :current_user, :model

  def initialize(current_user, model)
    Rails.logger.info '--------------- initialize called-------------------'
    Rails.logger.info current_user
    Rails.logger.info model
    @current_user = current_user
    @record = model
  end

  def index?
    @current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

controller:

```
controller do
    include Pundit
    protect_from_forgery
    rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized
    before_action :authenticate_admin_user!

    def index
        authorize current_admin_user
        super
    end

    private

        def user_not_authorized
           flash[:alert]="Access denied"
           redirect_to (request.referrer || admin_root_path)
        end
end
```

The log is as follows:

```
--------------- initialize called----------------------------------------

#<AdminUser:0x007f27733f8a80>
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 364ms (ActiveRecord: 312.8ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass):

app/policies/admin_user_policy.rb:13:in `index?'
app/admin/dashboard.rb:19:in `index'
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (4.8ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendering /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-5.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (39.5ms)
```

The weird part is, according to logs, `current_user=nil` and `model=#<AdminUser:0x007f27733f8a80>`

I swapped current_user with model my policy file as

```
def index?
  @record.admin?
end
```

And it works! 
I don't understand this strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pundit [policy doc](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#policies) says that it calls the `current_user` method to retrieve what to send into the first argument of the `initialize` method inside the Policy class. If you have configured ActiveAdmin to retrieve the current logged in user by using `current_admin_user`, then you have to override the pundit default method in your `ApplicationController` class like so: [Ref](https://github.com/elabs/pundit#customize-pundit-user)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  // ...
  def pundit_user
    current_admin_user // or whatever based on ActiveAdmin initializer config
  end
end
```

In order to make the defined policy working, you have to invoke `authorize` inside the controller action with the instance of the corresponding policy model. So if you have a `PostPolicy` and you want to authorize the `update` action, you have to do the following:

```
controller do
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    authorize @post // the current user will be automatically sent to the PostPolicy
    super
  end
end
```

The `authorize` method automatically infers that `Post` will have a matching `PostPolicy` class, and instantiates this class, handing in the current user and the given record. It then infers from the action name, that it should call `update?` on this instance of the policy. In this case, you can imagine that `authorize` would have done something like this:

```
unless PostPolicy.new(current_user, @post).update?
  raise Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, "not allowed to update? this #{@post.inspect}"
end
```

---

Having all these, in your case, if you want that a user should be authorized before viewing the list of all users, you can define the `AdminUserPolicy` like you have done already. Then in the `index` action of your `AdminUserController`,

```
controller do
  def index
    @users = AdminUser.all
    authorize @users // NOT `authorize current_admin_user`
    super
  end
end
```

You can pass a second argument to `authorize` if the name of the permission you want to check doesn't match the action name. For example:

```
def publish
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  authorize @post, :update?
  @post.publish!
  redirect_to @post
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That clears a lot of things. Queries like ```@users = Admin.all``` and ```@post=Post.find()``` would add to unnecessary processing, as my use case is only knowing if a user can or cannot use the methods like index, update etc. Is there a way to redirect them to spectific policy?  Or can I continue using current_admin_user?

Comment: glad to know that! would you pls elaborate what do you mean by `Is there a way to redirect them to specific policy?`

Comment: I just want to know "can this user view" or "can this user edit". I'm not concerned with @post variables. So querying them would be unnecessary.  But if I omit them, it wouldn't know which policy to check in. So how do I just say "authorize :index?"  without any input.

Comment: you can provide the class instead of an instance in the first argument of `authorize` method, e.g. `authorize Post`. But you must have to use some policy object in the first argument; be it an instance, a class or just a symbol (Headless Policy: https://github.com/elabs/pundit#headless-policies)

Comment: i see. you have another question on cancancan posted very recently here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095147/unable-to-use-cancancan-with-activeadmin-and-devise-undefined-method-dashboards#47095147. should I answer that too?

Comment: Thank you so much! That'll work just perfect. I chose pundit over cancancan, as I found it troublesome. I'm curious to know though.

Comment: actually i found `cancancan` to be more minimalistic than `pundit` while working with ActiveAdmin :) With the first one, I was able to setup authorization with less than 15 lines of code, whereas pundit would require at least all the boilerplate policies and then invoking `authorize` in every action. AA has optimized this task for cancancan in a cool way, so I really enjoyed it

Comment: When I observed the logs, CanCanCan's function calls were greater than those of pundit.

Comment: just answered your other question on cancancan: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47144739/1977104